# Clicking/selecting hidden attribute using ruby webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium

How do I click on the hidden input of the "Black" li element (or set it to "selected") using a ruby command?

```
 <li title="Bright Rose" class="memberHidden selected">
    <img id="swatch901489#1_0" class="colorSwatch" style="background:url('http://someimages.com/is/image/BLM/?&amp;$b=BLM/swatches/&amp;layer=0&amp;size=46,23&amp;src=is{$b$9/optimized/8201409_fpx.tif}&amp;cropN=0,0,2,1&amp;anchor=0,0&amp;layer=1&amp;size=23,23&amp;src=is{$b$0/optimized/8189800_fpx.tif}&amp;anchor=0,0&amp;posN=0.5,0&amp;layer=2&amp;op_sharpen=1&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=90,0&amp;hei=23') 46px 0 transparent;" title="Bright Rose" alt="Bright Rose">
    <input type="hidden" id="swatch901489#1_0_imgurl" value="9/optimized/8201409_fpx.tif">
 </li>

 <li title="Black" class="memberHidden ">
    <img id="swatch901489#2_0" class="colorSwatch" style="background:url('http://someimages.com/is/image/BLM/?&amp;$b=BLM/swatches/&amp;layer=0&amp;size=46,23&amp;src=is{$b$9/optimized/8201409_fpx.tif}&amp;cropN=0,0,2,1&amp;anchor=0,0&amp;layer=1&amp;size=23,23&amp;src=is{$b$0/optimized/8189800_fpx.tif}&amp;anchor=0,0&amp;posN=0.5,0&amp;layer=2&amp;op_sharpen=1&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=90,0&amp;hei=23') 23px 0 transparent;" title="Black" alt="Black">
    <input type="hidden" id="swatch901489#2_0_imgurl" value="0/optimized/8189800_fpx.tif">
  </li>
```

The element is on a third party website that I'm crawling. And for some reason, the chrome and firefox webdrivers can't seem to click on the "hidden" input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as below using [`execute_script`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#execute_script-instance_method):

```
script = <<-ejs
var y = document.getElementById('swatch901489#2_0_imgurl');
y.type= 'button';
return y;
ejs

driver.execute_script(script).click
```